# Is there a specific server name for ggcorrplot

Tags: r

I am trying ggcorrplot in my server output in R shiny. ggcorrplot is used to create correlation matrix. I tried with renderPlotly. The output is not getting displayed. I am sure its because of this only. When I run ggcorrplot outside R shiny, I am getting the output. Please advice. Or is there an alternate way to create correlation matrix under ggplot only. My Sample data dataframe is like below

```
install.packages("ggcorrplot")
library(ggcorrplot)
df
Date         Var1     Var2     Var3    Var4      
1/1/2019      12       21       34      23
1/1/2019      13       22       35      24
1/1/2019      14       22       35      25
1/1/2019      15       22       35      26

corr <- round(cor(df[2:5]),1)
ggcorrplot(corr,method = "circle",lab = TRUE,hc.order = TRUE)
```

When I use ggcorrplot under renderploty, there is no output

Comment: Usually, ggplots use `renderPlot` and `plotOutput`

Comment: Yeah, That is the reason I am not getting ggcorrplot output.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1) Use `renderPlot` and `plotOutput` for your ggplot object
2) wrap your ggplot object in `ggploty` and then use the `renderPlotly` and `plotlyOutput` calls. Your mileage will very with this option as not all aesthetics of ggplot are translated to plotly.

```
library(ggcorrplot)
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  #numericInput('n', 'Number of obs', n),
  plotOutput('plot'),
  plotlyOutput('plotly')
)

# Define the server code
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    cor <- cor(matrix(rnorm(100), ncol = 10))
    ggcorrplot(cor)
  })
  output$plotly <- renderPlotly({
    cor <- cor(matrix(rnorm(100), ncol = 10))
    ggplotly(ggcorrplot(cor))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks. Basically I need ggploty. But I think we cannot code like below ````ggploty(ggcorrplot(corr,method = "circle",lab = TRUE,hc.order = TRUE))````

Comment: You can do exactly that.

Comment: Please create a minimally working example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example